# Процедура z-буфера не работает в программе вращения трехмерного куба

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

Требуется закрасить невидимые грани в 3д кубе и никак не удается это сделать.

Для этого предпринял попытку использования функции glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST). Результата не последовало. Что можно исправить? Снизу представлен полный код. Спасибо!

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include<SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
sf::RenderWindow window;
double rotate_y = 0.0;
double rotate_x = 0.0;
double scale_x = 1.5;
double scale_y = 1.5;
double scale_z = 1.5;
double move_x = 0.0;
double move_y = 0.0;
double move_z = 0.0;
double x = 0.1;
double y = 0.1;
double z = 0.1;
double reverse = 1.0;
void display(){
//Очитска экрана
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();

//Поворот фигуры
glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

//расширить или сузить фигуру
glScalef(scale_x, scale_y, scale_z);

//переместить фигуру
glTranslatef(move_x, move_y, move_z);

glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse)// создаём красное перо
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse); // создаём зеленое перо
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse); // создаём синее перо
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse); // создаём розовое перо

glEnd();

// белая сторона сзади
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glEnd();

// фиолетовая сторона справа
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glEnd();

// зелёная сторона слева
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glEnd();

// синяя сторона сверху
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, 1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glEnd();

// красная сторона снизу
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, 1 * z * reverse);
glVertex3f(-1 * x * reverse, -1 * y * reverse, -1 * z * reverse);
glEnd();

}

void specialKeys(){
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
rotate_y += 0.5;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
rotate_y -= 0.5;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
rotate_x += 0.5;
else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
rotate_x -= 0.5;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q))//растяжение по z
scale_z -= 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
scale_z += 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Z))//растяжение по x
scale_x -= 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::C))
scale_x += 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::X))//растяжение по y
scale_y -= 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::V))
scale_y += 0.2;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) //двигаемся вправо по x
move_x += 0.1;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) //двигаемся влево по x
move_x -= 0.1;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) //двигаемся вверх по y
move_y += 0.1;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) //двигаемся вниз по y
move_y -= 0.1;

else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::R)) //двигаемся вниз по y
reverse *= -1;


}

int main(){
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "parallepiped");

while (true){
specialKeys();
window.display();
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
display();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
Sleep(30);
}

return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` следует вызывать до рисования, а не после.

Comment: К сожалению, вывод не изменился.